# Dockerfile copy timed out issue on Windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an issue when I run docker build on windows,

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install > npm.log 2>&1
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Command:

```
docker build --no-cache --rm -t fe-app:latest .
```

Issue:

```
Step 8/8 : COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: opengcs: copyWithTimeout: timed out (RunProcess: copy back from remotefs lstat /tmp/666137919f5d3c5661175c59a8f4f9051ed09611a5b560e7045828ec1f9c1ec7-mount/app/dist/uncommon/assets/data-test/service-staff-data/services-staff-ui-action.json)
```

Full Console output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.471MB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:alpine AS builder
alpine: Pulling from library/node
bdf0201b3a05: Pull complete
26f0dbb4f100: Pull complete
9af56c7c17da: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ca1695f514d5dc54b4812f8b9029b277f86b50e83870af47bfa4582af0ec695d
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:alpine
 ---> 1bdfa12c22dc
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 75a2de3672da
Removing intermediate container 75a2de3672da
 ---> 53a7b85e7278
Step 3/8 : COPY . .
 ---> a6fbf046933b
Step 4/8 : RUN npm cache clean --force
 ---> Running in 16148fc51784
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
Removing intermediate container 16148fc51784
 ---> 1f0b1dbf0a36
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install > npm.log 2>&1
 ---> Running in 8ac705a53089
Removing intermediate container 8ac705a53089
 ---> 6ae70108adb1
Step 6/8 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in ba84c78a50bb

> uncommon@0.0.0 build /app
> ng build


Date: 2019-04-18T13:22:02.537Z
Hash: 3d032830d7fde6941cf7
Time: 66267ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 270 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 237 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 23.9 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.14 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.69 MB [initial] [rendered]
Removing intermediate container ba84c78a50bb
 ---> 487cf0c02a50
Step 7/8 : FROM nginx:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/nginx
bdf0201b3a05: Already exists
08d74e155349: Pull complete
a9e2a0b35060: Pull complete
d9e2304ab8d0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:61e3db30b1334b1fa0a2e71b86625188f76653565d515d5f74ecc55a8fb91ce9
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:alpine
 ---> 0be75340bd9b
Step 8/8 : COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: opengcs: copyWithTimeout: timed out (RunProcess: copy back from remotefs lstat /tmp/666137919f5d3c5661175c59a8f4f9051ed09611a5b560e7045828ec1f9c1ec7-mount/app/dist/uncommon/assets/data-test/service-staff-data/services-staff-ui-action.json)
```

I run the same on my local env and runs successfully, but I have the issue on the server, when I run this on the server it's generated the folder c:\tmp\666137919f5d3c5661175c59a8f4f9051ed09611a5b560e7045828ec1f9c1ec7-mount, on my local env don't.

I hope someone give me a hint, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution on how to fix the issue, is a solution on how to avoid the issue:

First compressed the folder and then copy only the zip file.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

RUN apk add zip

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install > npm.log 2>&1
RUN npm run build

RUN zip -r npm.zip /app/dist

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN apk add unzip

COPY --from=builder /app/npm.zip /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN unzip npm.zip
```